# How do I cache dynamic header/footer in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, before-filter

Say I have a simple app with the following layout

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/header' %>  
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

My header and footer partials are pretty simple but they require dynamic data which takes a a few ms to fetch from the db. Right now, I get the header data with a before_action: method in my application controller since it's need on a all pages (except Ajax calls):

```
before_action :prepare_header

private 
def prepare_header
    @news = ... 
end
```

How can I cache either the prepare_header action or header.erb.html.
I am using Rails 4.0.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with fragment caching in the view.

Your `@news` variable is calculated based on some data, for example `params[:a], params[:b] and params[:c]`. Based on that you can wrap your header (and then partial) with a cache block

```
<% cache([params[:a], params[:b], params[:c], 'header']) do %>
  you html code here
<% end %>
```

with that you can have a cached version of your partial depending on the desired control variables. Check [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache) for more on view caching.

A good practice is to add more  control to the `cache_key` in order to invalidate it on demand, like:

`cache([cache_key_1, cache_key_2, version_number])`

when something changes you bump the version_number and invalidate accordingly!

And of course an `expires_at` parameter.

**UPDATE**

For action caching you can try [this gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching). And pass your desired params in an
`if: Proc { ... }`

parameter

Comment: Wouldn't this only cache the view itself but the before_action method is still going to execute? That's what I am trying to cache. The view rendering is negligible for me since it doesn't hit the database at all so it's pretty fast.

Comment: @Rorchackh well you asked for either the `html.erb` template or the action, this answer is for the template. I updated the answer with action_caching as well.